# Two sets of cache with one server (Varnish Cache)

Tags: reverse-proxy, varnish, varnish-vcl

Is it possible to setup Varnish Cache with two independent cache stores?

Then based on a http custom header either use cache1 or cache2.

For example:

- Request 1 comes in with header (store=Cache1) this should go to the Cache1
  store on Varnish cache
- Request 2 comes in which is exactly like Request 1 but with header (store=Cache2) this should go to the Cache2 store on Varnish cache

This use case occurs when the backend responds with different body based on the header (but with the same url) - a legitimate use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deal with this exactly as described by partitioning Varnish cache, similar to [putting Varnish static files cache separately](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish-static-files-cache).

But what you want is actually much more simple. Your particular case should be addressed easily by adjusting VCL. You will only need to tell Varnish that the cache should be different based on that particular header. So in your VCL, you would specify:

```cpp
sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.store) {
        hash_data(req.http.store);
    }
}
```

The `vcl_hash` specifies that cache should be different depending on the value of `store` HTTP header.

Comment: Holy crap dude, that worked exactly how I envisioned it! Thanks!